# Why are there 2 creators in the metadata in my NFT on Solana?

Tags: solana, nft, candy-machine

I have been playing around with Solana, deploying NFTs on the devnet. I noticed one thing that when I mint an NFT, it has 2 creators, even though I mention only one in the metadata. I am minting the collection using candymachine v2.

I would like to know what the purpose of the other address is.

[image: on the chain]

[image: metadata in the json]

Answer (score 0):

Metaplex has a requirement where the the creators array should include the address of the person minting so the address with the share of 0 is that and the other address with the share as 100 is the actualy artist/creator

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer was wrong because it didn't mention the candy machine creator and said the address with index=0 is the person who minted that nft.
So, please review candy machine v1 and v2 for this misunderstanding.
I will review v1 for DeGods collection and v2 for Honeyland collection.

**Candy Machine v1(Deprecated)- who is the first creator in the creator's array?**

[DeGods collection address](https://solscan.io/collection/a38e8d9d1a16b625978803a7d4eb512bc20ff880c8fd6cc667944a3d7b5e4acf)

If you open each of DeGods collection nfts, first creator should be this:
*9MynErYQ5Qi6obp4YwwdoDmXkZ1hYVtPUqYmJJ3rZ9Kn*

For each nft of this collection, if we open first transaction(creating nft) and search for the address above(9Myn...) we can see

[image]

transaction log just prints candy machine in front of the address(9Myn..)

alright, Go on, and let's see next collection.

**Candy Machine v2 - who is the first creator in the creator's array?**

[Honeyland collection address](https://solscan.io/collection/01e2e95ee387485979dfc4a955aa541f25dc692878730bc19582fb241c1c4d07)

If you open each of Honeyland collection nfts, the first creator should be this:
*55kdnoo2YJDtbWvEHYuXjGoyBnm2zRTKsz7FPzdzhRwg*

For each nft of this collection, if we open the first transaction(creating nft) and search for the address above(55kd...) we can see

[image]

In cmv2, transaction logs print **candy machine creator** obviously.

So, the question is, what is the candy machine creator?
it's a PDA of candy machine. With cm creator you can fetch it's info like mint price, creators, live date, etc.

if you have candy machine id, you can find it's creator PDA like this:

```
    const getCandyMachineCreator = async (candyMachine: PublicKey): Promise<[PublicKey, number]> => {
    return await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([Buffer.from('candy_machine'), candyMachine.toBuffer()], CANDY_MACHINE_PROGRAM);
```

};

hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't say the address with index 0 is the person who minted the NFT, I said that address who mints the nft is required to be in the array and that usually the royalty share for that address is set to 0, yes i did forget to mention the candy machine pda

Comment: To be fair I read it as the first way and thought you'd made a mistake too.